# Issue with multiple UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark applied on single UITableCell touch

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

so I have a lot of cells in my UITableView and on touching a cell, additional cells that are just out of view also have ticks applied. I believe this is because the cells are being reused or something due to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`

Heres my code:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone){
                [addPapersSelectedRowsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

            }
            else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                [addPapersSelectedRowsArray removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
            }


    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }



    NSDictionary *currentPapersSecltion = [papersDataDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[currentPapersSecltion objectForKey:@"Title"]]; 



   return cell;

}
```

Also pulling data from a .plist in `viewDidLoad`:

```
 //Load papers data from the local plist
    papersDataDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"papers.plist"]] objectForKey:@"Rows"];
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks guys!

Dex

Comment: Post code for your cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource method

Comment: Where is your cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method ? and make changes in your delegate method as per @samfisher answer.

Answer (score 3):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath which you need to set your checkmark according to whether or not the cell has been selected.

```
if ([addPapersSelectedRowsArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[indexPath row]]]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
return cell;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   // add this line
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone){
        [addPapersSelectedRowsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    }
    else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [addPapersSelectedRowsArray removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    }
  //add this line as well
   [tableView reloadData];
```