# tableView CellAccessoryCheckmark showing up in multiple locations

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to set up my UITableView to put up a checkmark when the user does an action I'm listening for.  I can make the checkmarks show up, but they're showing up in multiple locations.

Right now my cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [TableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

if(myCheckmarks[indexPath.row] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1])
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

cell.textLabel.text = [benchmarkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

and I'm using this to set the array it's reading from:

```
[myCheckmarks replaceObjectAtIndex:tempIndex withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

In this implementation though, the checkmarks don't even show up until the table is moved, but that was somewhat expected.

This is my old code that would set the checkmark immediately, but I still have the whole 'multiple checkmarks when I scroll at all' problem:

```
        UITableViewCell *cell = [metricTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = nil;
        NSLog(@"1 else hit");
```

That was when the user hit a button, and it would immediately update since the code was called then.  It would still end up with checkmarks all over the place if the table was moved though.

How do I set this up so I can use the accessory checkmark on a table that's anywhere from 11-27 elements long, but only shows ten at a time (for UI design reasons)?

Edit: I need to add that in my cellForRowAtIndexPath, the text is never duplicated.  It's reading an array of 11-27 items and displays correctly each time for each cell, but when I try to use the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckMark, THAT will show up in multiple locations when I scroll the UITableView.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681035/issue-with-multiple-uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark-applied-on-single-uitablec.

Comment: all these questions stem from improper reuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "checkmarks in multiple locations" means checkmarks on individual cells that shouldn't have them, I suspect it is using a dequeued cell which had its accessoryType set to UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark.  If you were subclassing your UITableViewCell, you could reset it to UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator in prepareForReuse, or in your code above, if the cell is not nil, set it to UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator
```